# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting this error again and again even though I have used "multiDexEnabled true " in my gradle.Here is my java file in which I am getting the error :

```
package com.itjobnotification.first.app;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.graphics.Color;
        import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
        import android.provider.Settings;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.database.DataSetObserver;
        import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
        import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.view.Window;
        import android.view.WindowManager;
        import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

        import android.widget.ListAdapter;

        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.util.Log;

        import com.gc.materialdesign.views.Button;
        import com.gc.materialdesign.widgets.Dialog;
        import com.google.gson.Gson;

        import android.content.SharedPreferences;
        import android.widget.CheckBox;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Arrays;

        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.content.DialogInterface;
        import android.widget.Spinner;
        import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
        import android.text.Html;


        public class signupActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnTaskCompleted {
            AlertDialog dialog;
            com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat skills;
            ArrayList<String> selectedItems;
            Spinner ctc;
            private Toolbar toolbar;
            formBody fb;
            int index = 0, i = 0;
            String[] ar = new String[10];

            String item;
            Button submit;
            EditText name, email, company, exp, promo, location;
            CardView cv;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

                toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Get Started!!");


                skills = (com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat) findViewById(R.id.chooseSkills);
                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.terms);
                submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
                Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.college);
                Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.loc);
                name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
                email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
                company = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company);
                exp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.exp);
                ctc = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ctc);
                CardView cv = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_view);

                final formBody fb = new formBody();

                // first spinner - college
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                        R.array.college, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner.setAdapter(
                        new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                                adapter,
                                R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected,
                                this));


                //second spinner with job location
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                        R.array.location, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner1.setAdapter(
                        new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                                adapter1,
                                R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected_loc,
                                this));

                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                        R.array.category, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                ctc.setAdapter(
                        new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                                adapter2,
                                R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected_ctc,
                                this));
                ;


                // skill button, dialog opens with the options when clicked
                skills.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        final CharSequence[] items = new String[]{"Java", "C/C++", "Analytics", "Android", "Distributed Systems", "UI", "Python", "Ruby"};
                        selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
                        selectedItems.add("Java");
                        selectedItems.add("C/C++");
                        selectedItems.add("Analytics");
                        selectedItems.add("Android");
                        selectedItems.add("Distributed Systems");
                        selectedItems.add("UI");
                        selectedItems.add("Python");
                        selectedItems.add("Ruby");
                        AlertDialog.Builder dbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(signupActivity.this)

                       .setTitle("Select your skills")
                        .setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
                                new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                                    // indexSelected contains the index of item (of which checkbox checked)
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected,
                                                        boolean isChecked) {
                                        if (isChecked) {
                                            item =  selectedItems.get(indexSelected);
                                            Log.d("hello123", item);
                                            ar[index++] = item;
                                        } else if (selectedItems.contains(indexSelected)) {
                                            selectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
                                        }
                                    }
                                })

                                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                        dialog = dbuilder.create();//AlertDialog dialog; create like this outside onClick
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                });

                submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
                        builder.scheme("http");
                        builder.authority(QuickstartPreferences.SERVER_IP);
                        builder.path(QuickstartPreferences.SIGNUP_PAGE);

                        fb.name = name.getText().toString();
                        //      fb.ctc = ctc.getText().toString();
                        fb.exp = exp.getText().toString();
                        fb.email = email.getText().toString();
                        fb.company = company.getText().toString();
                        //   fb.location = location.getText().toString();

                        if (checkEmpty(fb.name, "Name can't be empty")) {
                            return;
                        }
                        if (checkEmpty(fb.email, "Email can't be empty")) {
                            return;
                        }
                        if (checkEmpty(fb.company, "Company can't be empty")) {
                            return;
                        }
                        if (checkEmpty(fb.exp, "Experience can't be empty")) {
                            return;
                        }
                        if (fb.ctc.isEmpty()) {
                            fb.ctc = "0";
                        }

                        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.loc);
                        String str = null;
                        try {
                            str = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select job location",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        fb.location = str;

                        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.college);
                        String cg = null;
                        try {
                            cg = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select college",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        fb.college = cg;
                        if (index > 0) {
                            fb.skill_set = Arrays.copyOfRange(ar, 0, index);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Skills can't be empty",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }


                        String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                        fb.device_id = android_id;

                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        String postdata = gson.toJson(fb);
                        String myUrl = builder.build().toString();
                        new Dbtask(signupActivity.this, postdata).execute(myUrl);
                    }
                });

                // terms and conditions textView
                textView.setClickable(true);
                textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                String text = "I agree to <a href='http://itjobnotification.com/terms.html'> terms and conditions. </a>";
                textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
                textView.setTextSize(10);

                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, "Prompt!!", "Just add few details of you and get started");
                dialog.show();


            }

            public boolean checkEmpty(String str, String message) {
                if (str.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;

            }

            @Override
            public void onTaskCompleted(String str) {
                //Log.e("nimish", "signup completed");
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SIGNUP, true).apply();
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
                startService(intent);
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Thanks for Signing up !!!")
                        .setMessage("We will notify you when we find suitable jobs for you")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Log.d("hello", String.valueOf(QuickstartPreferences.SIGNUP));
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star)
                        .show();
                   /* Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,"Thanks for Signing up !!!", "We will notify you when we find suitable jobs for you");
                    dialog.setCancelable(false);
                    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    dialog.setOnAcceptButtonClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();  */
            }

            @Override
            public void onResume() {  // After a pause OR at startup
                super.onResume();
                //Log.e("nimish", "refresh");

            }

            public class NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter, ListAdapter {
                protected static final int EXTRA = 1;
                protected SpinnerAdapter adapter;
                protected Context context;
                protected int nothingSelectedLayout;
                protected int nothingSelectedDropdownLayout;
                protected LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


                public NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                        SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter,
                        int nothingSelectedLayout, Context context) {
                    this(spinnerAdapter, nothingSelectedLayout, -1, context);
                }


                public NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter, int nothingSelectedLayout, int nothingSelectedDropdownLayout, Context context) {
                    this.adapter = spinnerAdapter;
                    this.context = context;
                    this.nothingSelectedLayout = nothingSelectedLayout;
                    this.nothingSelectedDropdownLayout = nothingSelectedDropdownLayout;
                    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                }

                @Override
                public final View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    // This provides the View for the Selected Item in the Spinner, not
                    // the dropdown (unless dropdownView is not set).
                    if (position == 0) {
                        return getNothingSelectedView(parent);
                    }
                    return adapter.getView(position - EXTRA, null, parent); // Could re-use
                    // the convertView if possible.
                }


                protected View getNothingSelectedView(ViewGroup parent) {
                    return layoutInflater.inflate(nothingSelectedLayout, parent, false);
                }

                @Override
                public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    // Android BUG! http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17128 -
                    // Spinner does not support multiple view types
                    if (position == 0) {
                        return nothingSelectedDropdownLayout == -1 ?
                                new View(context) :
                                getNothingSelectedDropdownView(parent);
                    }
                    // Could re-use the convertView if possible, use setTag...
                    return adapter.getDropDownView(position - EXTRA, null, parent);
                }


                protected View getNothingSelectedDropdownView(ViewGroup parent) {
                    return layoutInflater.inflate(nothingSelectedDropdownLayout, parent, false);
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    int count = adapter.getCount();
                    return count == 0 ? 0 : count + EXTRA;
                }

                @Override
                public Object getItem(int position) {
                    return position == 0 ? null : adapter.getItem(position - EXTRA);
                }

                @Override
                public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                    return 0;
                }

                @Override
                public int getViewTypeCount() {
                    return 1;
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {
                    return position >= EXTRA ? adapter.getItemId(position - EXTRA) : position - EXTRA;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean hasStableIds() {
                    return adapter.hasStableIds();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isEmpty() {
                    return adapter.isEmpty();
                }

                @Override
                public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
                    adapter.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
                }

                @Override
                public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
                    adapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                    return position != 0; // Don't allow the 'nothing selected'
                    // item to be picked.
                }

            }
        }
```

Here is the logcat which is showing the error in AlertDialog.Builder:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                Process: com.itjobnotification.first.app, PID: 3403
                java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.itjobnotification.first.app.signupActivity$1$3
                at com.itjobnotification.first.app.signupActivity$1.onClick(signupActivity.java:142)
                at com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat.onDraw(ButtonFlat.java:83)
```

`

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.itjobnotification.first.app" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <activity
                android:name=".SplashActivity"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

            <activity
                android:name=".signupActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                android:label="Get Started!!"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
            </activity>

            <receiver
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
                android:exported="true"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <service
                android:name=".RegistrationIntentService"
                android:exported="false"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            </service>
            <service
                android:name=".MyGcmListenerService"
                android:exported="false"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>

            <activity
                android:name=".jobshow"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_jobshow"
                android:theme="@style/DarkAction" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".list"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_list"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".Test1Activity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_test1"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".chatActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_chat"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".quiz"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_quiz"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            </activity>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

            <activity
                android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
            <!-- Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement -->
            <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />

            <receiver
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
                android:exported="true" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>


        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: check if the `signupActivity` exist in the manifest

Comment: Yeah.It does as you can see above.

Comment: do yourself a big favor, don't enable multi dex, unless there is an absolute need for it. Also, please post your dependencies section of your build.gradle file

Answer (score 1):

1. Add this line in your manifest code:

   ```
    <application

   android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">

       </application>
   ```
2. You also have to add the following to your gradle file dependencies:

   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
3. And Finally You also need to add following into your java file in OnCreate method:

   MultiDex.install(this);

For More Reference Checkout this Link:
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Answer (score 0):

Multidex creates multiple dex files if you have more than 65k methods in your project. If the library requires it then you need to use it. If you define it in the build.gradle you should be fine. No need to add it programatically.

In build.gradle file

1.Add

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

2. Then add

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

3. Then add

```
<activity> 
    com.itjobnotification.first.app.signupactivity 
</activity>
```

to your manifest with full name including package name. And make class name starting with capital like SignUpActivity.